# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -155

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping

I've encoutered this error when using native query. The query selects only numbers, texts and timestamp.

```
@Query(value = "select ti.id, ti.timestamp, ti.fuel_station_id, ti.cash_register_id, sum(cast(dsc.discount as numeric(12,2))) as saving
from transaction_info as ti
join discount dsc on ti.id = dsc.transaction_id
where ti.user_id = :userId
and ti.timestamp >= :timeFrom")
Page<Saving> findSavingsListByLmsUserAfterTimestamp(@Param("userId") long userId, @Param("timeFrom") Instant timeFrom, Pageable pageable);
```

`Saving` is an interface

```
public interface Saving {
    String getId();
    Instant getTimestamp();
    Long getFuelStationId();
    Long getCashRegisterId();
    Double getSaving();
}
```

I suspect the problem is either in `timestamp` or `saving` as I use other types (String, Long) in other native queries without problem.

Comment: JDBC doesn't define a JDBC type -155, so likely it's a type code specific to your JDBC driver. For Hibernate, a mapping for that column type would need to be defined in the dialect to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, the problem was in `timestamp` which Hibernate / JDBC was not able to convert to Instant. I've solved it by converting timestamp to varchar in SQL and change the type in Java interface to String.

```
@Query(value = "select ti.id, convert(varchar, ti.timestamp, 120) as timestamp, ti.fuel_station_id, ti.cash_register_id, sum(cast(dsc.discount as numeric(12,2))) as saving
from transaction_info as ti
join discount dsc on ti.id = dsc.transaction_id
where ti.user_id = :userId
and ti.timestamp >= :timeFrom")
Page<Saving> findSavingsListByLmsUserAfterTimestamp(@Param("userId") long userId, @Param("timeFrom") Instant timeFrom, Pageable pageable);
```

The `Saving` interface has changed to

```
public interface Saving {
    String getId();
    String getTimestamp();
    Long getFuelStationId();
    Long getCashRegisterId();
    Double getSaving();
}
```

Maybe changing `Instant timestamp` to `Date timestamp` would help, I did'nt try.